# Synchronization data upload not working

Tags: synchronization

I am using Microsoft sync framework to upload data from client to the server . I have successfully provisioned the server and the client .When I try to execute the ExecuteSync code , it says successfully uploaded but data is not available at the server side SQL server database. Any help on this highly appreciated

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using System.Data;
namespace ExecuteSync
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string scopename = "";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(@"");

            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(@"");

            SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();


            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopename, clientConn);


            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopename, serverConn);


            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;


            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);


            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();



            Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Uploads Failed: " + syncStats.UploadChangesFailed);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }




        static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);

            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        }
    }
}
```